# Drop down menu placement & width issue

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have an issue with the "About" drop down menu here: http://pamperland.net/selindobeta/

I'd like the child links to have a width of about 120px and have different background colors than their parent. Somehow I added those properties and this is what I get. The parent link doubles the size and shifts down, the child links not having the color properties specified.

Comment: Could you make a fiddle for us

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 630px;
    top: 136px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the background is changing, becase the first a tag in the li is also selected, you should write:

```
li:hover ul a
    {
       background: #2f3036;
       color: #fff;
    }
```

intead of

```
li:hover a
```

and, the double sizing happens becase of the floating, just use display:block, instead:

```
li > ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
ul li:hover > ul{
    position: absolute; <-- Added
    top: 40px;
}
ul > li{
    position: relative;
}
li > ul > li{
    position: static;
}
```